# document.getElementsByClassName('active'); to hide and show a div is not working. suggest an alternative

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#cprofile').click(function(){
    if(!$(this).parent().hasClass('active')) {
        var active_element = document.getElementsByClassName('active');
        $(active_element).removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    }
    $('.client_container').hide();
    $('#cprofile_container').show();
});
```

`document.getElementsByClassName('active');` does not work in internet explorer.
plz suggest other alternative.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, why are you using the long-winded plain Javascript function instead of a jQuery selector?

Comment: Should work fine in IE9 and above ?

Comment: **getElementsByClassName** is only supported from IE 9. You might be testing on an older IE browser. http://caniuse.com/#feat=getelementsbyclassname

Comment: For older versions, here's a [polyfill](http://robertnyman.com/2008/05/27/the-ultimate-getelementsbyclassname-anno-2008/), but you're already using jQuery, so there's really no point!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Class Selector (“.class”)](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) instead of `getElementsByClassName`

```
$('.active').removeClass('active');
```

Comment: guys thank you but i dont know how to check which class is active.

Comment: Your statement is not clear to me, do you want to check what elements have class active?

Comment: How to find out which class has been clicked

Comment: this.className will give you class of event source object

Comment: How to find out which class is previously active   @Adil

Comment: $(this).parent().addClass('active'); prviousActiveObject = $(this).parent(); declare prviousActiveObject on global scope outside function, can you make a fiddle and tell me what exactly you want

Comment: Actually i have 5 tabs one is active while loading and has selected colors.When i click on the other i want to unselect(deactivate) the previous one and make the clicked one active which changes the background color

Comment: <ul class="nav">
<li><a id="a" href="#">home</a></li>
<li ><a id="b" href="#">contact us</a></li>
<li ><a id="c" href="#">mail</a></li>
<li><a id="d" href="#">aaaaaa</a></li>
<li class="active"><a id="g" href="#">aaaaa</a></li>
<li><a id="e" href="#">aaaaa</a></li>
<li ><a id="f" href="#">aaaaa</a></li>
</ul>    it is something like that